# airodump error: ioctl(SIOCSIFFLAGS) failed: Name not unique on network

Tags: wireless

```
# airodump-ng mon0
ioctl(SIOCSIFFLAGS) failed: Name not unique on network
```

Tried most of the things like Backports but always gave me few error

Comment: Could you please edit the title so we know what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 9):

Follow [this advice](http://www.eenyhelp.com/answer/bug-775420-aircrack-ng-airodump-ng-wont-start-help-215552518.html#215552519):

> 1) First stop NetworkManager
>
> `$ service network-manager stop`
>
> And retry creating mon0 with airmon-ng.

This should solve the problem, you should longer have the 
`ioctl(SIOCSIFFLAGS) failed: Name not unique on network` message.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VM Network interfaces is a normal issue, thoses interfaces take the localhost name and replicate the Interface name, try to change the localhost in /etc/hosts, if that is not working to you, let me know